# Custom login URL in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am a newbie in django and I was experting different options in Django. I have created a class based view which requires user authentication to view the web page. I am using the inbuilt LoginView.

When the url pattern is specified as follows

```
url(r'^login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(),name='login'),
```

it is correctly redirected to login page.

But when I give

```
url(r'^restaurant/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(),name='login'),
```

I get a 404 when trying to access the page that requires user authentication.
But when I manually go to that url in browser, it works perfectly fine.
Why is that? Shouldn't it both cases work?

Comment: Note that apart from when you are using `include()`, your regexes should end with dollars (e.g. `r'^login/$'` and `r'^restaurant/login/$'`). Otherwise the URL pattern will match `/restaurant/login/` but also `/restaurant/login/something-else/`.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you need to set `LOGIN_URL` in your settings:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/restaurant/login/'
```

or, it's better to use the URL pattern name, then you don't have to update your settings when you change the login URL

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

Comment: Isnt django looking for 'login' specified in the name parameter of url and then reversing it into 'restaurant/login'?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. By default, the [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/) redirects to [`settings.LOGIN_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_URL). However this defaults to `/accounts/login/`, it doesn't reverse by default.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I'd fully understand your question, just try to give a stupid answer.

> Django 2.1.7

1. use namespace&url name in settings, if you have your own login view just change *admin* to your url namespace and name your view as 'login'

```py
# settings.py
LOGIN_URL = 'admin:login'
```

2. then the `login_required` decorator will direct you the correct login page.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required()
def month_archive(request, year, month):
    production_list = Production.objects.month_archive(year, month)
    context = {'production_list': production_list}
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'production/production_list.html', context)
```

3. If it's a Class Based View, add decorator to urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    path('', login_required(views.ProductionList.as_view()), name='production-list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.month_archive, name='production-month'),
]
```

Comment: For class-based views, the official way to do this is with [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).